# Bash autocomplete with vim command

Tags: bash, arch-linux, vim, autocomplete

In bash, autocompletion of paths has recently stopped working when issuing `vim` commands where the path is deeper than two directories (it continues to work as expected with other commands, such as `ls` and `cd`).

For example, if I type `ls .config/btsync/bt` and then press TAB, it expands to `ls .config/btsync/btsync.conf`.

If I type `vim .config/bt` and then press TAB, it expands to `vim .config/btsync/`.

However, if I type `vim .config/btsync/bt` and then press TAB, nothing happens (I would expect it to expand to `vim  .config/btsync/btsync.conf`, as in the `ls` example, above.

I get the same issue when running as my own user and when running as su.

I read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126300/bash-autocomplete-variables-for-other-commands-than-cd) which mentioned an issue with older versions of bash-completion but I'm running 2.1-5.

UPDATE:
After some additional testing, I've found that the root issue is that bash will *only* complete directory names, not filenames.

**UPDATE:
It turns out that `bash-completion` was the overall cause.  See my second comment on the accepted answer.**

Any suggestions as to the potential cause of this behaviour would be gratefully received!

Comment: Post your `.bashrc`!

Comment: Link to my `.bashrc` posted, as demanded.

Comment: Removed links to .bashrc, .aliases and .functions as not pertininent to the issue now that the cause has been discovered.

Comment: same issue on Debian 9, some installations but not all :$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some more research for you and here is what I found - the key to autocompletion is the `bash` command `complete`. You can print the rules for `vim` using:

```
complete -p vim
```

Likewise you can remove these specific rules with:

```
complete -r vim
```

This command resets it to defaults - the usual paths and file names completion without any extra logic. That's probably what you want.

For more info check out `help complete` or `man bash` and look for the section about `complete` command (it's a bash built-in, hence it's documented in the bash manpage).

One last point - the above changes only affect the current `bash` session, if you want to remove the vim rules after every login put the `complete -r vim` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That did it.  Many, many thanks. The `complete -p vim` command returned `complete -F _filedir_xspec vim` which was removed by the `complete -r vim` command, resolving the issue. I'm going to do some reading on the `complete` command and the information returned by the -p switch.  Slightly puzzled why this behaviour changed so will investigate that, too.

Comment: It seems as though bash-completion was the culprit after all.  The `_filedir_xspec` function in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` only completes directories.  I've uninstalled `bash-completion`, removed the `complete -r vim` line from my `.bashrc` and rebooted and `vim` now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Bash by defaults autocompletes only path and file names. However the mechanism is extensible and bash can be taught to perform different autocompletion for different programs. For example for `git` it can autocomplete the sub-command names (clone, commit) and revisions instead of just pathnames. Sometimes it's handy, sometimes quite annoying - for example when `gzip -d` refuses to autocomplete filenames that don't have the `.gz` extension.

Bash completion is usually configured in `/etc/bash_completion.d` - you will probably find a file called `vim` in there. That's the file that contains the autocompletion rules for `vim` commandline.

Now you've got two options:

1. Either fix the file to autocomplete paths as users probably expect anyway.
2. Remove the file to disable the special `vim` rules and only perform the default path autocompletion.

And of course file a bug report that outlines the problem so that it gets fixed in the future versions :)

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation :) I've had a look in `/etc/bash_completion.d` and there is only an `hg` file present (for Mercurial).  Very strange.

Comment: Then it must be elsewhere. Try `/usr/share/bash-completion/` or list all the files from `vim` package or from `bash` or `bash-completion` packages (not sure how is it called on ArchLinux). It'll be there somewhere.

Comment: Listing files from the `bash-completion` package shows `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions` does contain rules for many programmes, but not `vim`.  Listing files installed with the `vim` package doesn't show any completion-related files and searching the whole system using `find / -name vim` also shows no completion-related files.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps could you reinstall bash-completion :
    `apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion`

And have a look at file /etc/bash.bashrc :
    `nano /etc/bash.bashrc`

And verify that the following line are well uncommented:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
fi
```

Then, restart your terminal session

Comment: I tried removing `bash-completion`, testing the `vim` behaviour and then reinstalling `bash-completion` and testing but I still experienced the same problem in both circumstances.  The lines you've listed are not present in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  This line is, however `[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion   ] && . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`